# 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '4.7.1 Connection temporarily blocked by local policy; try again later

Tags: email, exception, smtp

I've started getting heaps of exceptions and my Cart2Quote emails are no longer sending. Our email server is working fine and our Cart2Quote settings haven't changed since it was working.

It looks like it may be an issue with SMTP Pro, but, again, the settings have no changed since we were in a working status.

**How do I trace the exception to find the real problem?**

**Or, what does the error** (Connection temporarily blocked by local policy; try again later) **actually mean?**

```
2015-07-06T15:45:02+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '4.7.1 Connection temporarily blocked by local policy; try again later
' in /var/www/sites/mbs/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/sites/mbs/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(220, 300)
#1 /var/www/sites/mbs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#2 /var/www/sites/mbs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#3 /var/www/sites/mbs/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#4 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Queue.php(98): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#5 [internal function]: Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#6 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#8 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /var/www/sites/mbs/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#12 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weekend, we migrated our Development installation onto our Live server, causing hundreds of emails to be automatically sent in a giant batch. This got our mail server blacklisted. Once we got that cleared up, everything was fine.

**TL;DR** If you're having this problem, check to see if your mail server has been blacklisted.